# how to convert a video to black and white color without any shades

Tags: video

How can a video be converted to black and white color. It should not have any shades of gray color. Only two colors - black and white.

There are many options to convert colored video to grayscale - which will have various shades of black. But I want video to only contain two colors.

Is there any source where such videos can be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only familiar with Vegas Pro, but I think many NLEs will do the same.

Begin by applying the desaturate effect or the 100% black and white effect. Then engage the Brightness and contrast effect, adjust the contrast until you have only black and white, you may need to toy with the brightness as well but not much.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which editor / effects SW you're using, you may find this as an existing effect.

If you have to do it yourself, first desaturate -- convert to greyscale.

If you then simply increase the contrast until only pure black and white remain, you may be disappointed in the result, because video generally has a low-ish APL (average picture level), so most of the image will turn black as it's stretched to the two extremes.

To counteract this, first (or simultaneously) increase the gamma of the image, to raise the APL into a centered range. Only then max out the contrast.

Playing with your actual images is the only way to know where the knobs should be turned, but it's important to know what knobs there are and what they do.